# For appointment on 21st February, 2020 in PSK office India, when should we apply online? what option comes to change address details?

Tags: indian-citizens, passports

In order to get an appointment 21st February, 2020 in PSK office India, when should we apply online to get the same date or get options to choose the date before or after my desired date? 
And, if I want to change just a minor correction in my address, then should I apply as complete address change while applying it online. If yes, then should I bring the address proof as well?